# Highlight prettified code

Tags: font-lock, highlighting, characters, tex, prettify-symbols-mode

is there a way of highlighting a prettified phrase? Something like:

```lisp
   (push '("\\qquad " . "⧢") prettify-symbols-alist)
   (highlight-phrase "⧢" 'shadow)
   (highlight-phrase "\\qquad" 'shadow)
```

(which does not work).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-h v prettify-symbols-alist` says that each element of the alist should be `(SYMBOL . CHARACTER)`. Actually, it seems that what it means by `SYMBOL` here is not a Lisp symbol but a string that names the textual symbol to prettify.

But `CHARACTER` there really does mean that you need to use a Lisp character (or a list or vector, as the doc says). You're using a string `"⧢"` instead of the character `?⧢`.  Try this instead:

```lisp
(push '("\\qquad" . ?⧢) prettify-symbols-alist)
```

Dunno about the symbol you want highlighted. Is the trailing space really part of it? I guessed maybe you meant the TeX name `\qquad`.
It seems to work for me, in TeX mode.

You can highlight the displayed `⧢` using `highlight-regexp` or `highlight-phrase`, using regexp `\\qquad`, as you tried. It works for me.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am writing LaTeX. Auctex has `("\\qquad" . 10722)` in `prettify-symbols-alist`, which is the symbol. This does not solve the highlighting problem, though.

Comment: 10722 = ?⧢. It's clearer to use ?⧢ in the code, but you can use 10722 instead.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to fix highlightning?

Comment: Updated - works for me, with either `highlight-regexp` or `highlight-phrase`.

Comment: even after `M-x prettify-symbols-mode`?

Comment: Yes............................. You might have to first remove anything remaining from previous tries, e.g. other values in the alist or other values submitted for highlighting.

Comment: Thanks again. Your responses made me try again: what works as desired, is `(highlight-phrase "\\\\qquad" 'shadow)` and this was my mistake…

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you. Feel free to accept the answer ;-).